# Create Smart Utility Padding and Margin classes with LESS?

Tags: html, css, less

I feel like there would a way do create a set of smarter utility classes then what I have where I can add a class like `<div class="margin-top-6">` to a tag within the HTML itself and LESS would be able to run with it and apply a CSS rule that would add 6px of margin to the top of that element.

Is this possible?

I'm a huge believer in working smarter not harder but right now what I have a crazy clunky and it feels like it could be smarter with a little bit more LESS knowledge.

So I wanted to know is if there is something better.  Here is a sampling of just the padding part of what I have.  The full code is repeated just like below up to 25px of each class set, but it would be great to have the limit completely flexible setup.  I was thinking something with variables or mixins or something where you would have a LESS rule looking like `.padding-@var1-@var2`, then check if the `vars` are present and if so, what are they, then...etc.

### LESS

```
.padding {

    &-1  { padding:  1px !important; }
    &-2  { padding:  2px !important; }
    &-3  { padding:  3px !important; }
    &-...

    &-height-1  { padding-top:  1px !important; padding-bottom:  1px !important; }
    &-height-2  { padding-top:  2px !important; padding-bottom:  2px !important; }
    &-height-3  { padding-top:  3px !important; padding-bottom:  3px !important; }
    &-...

    &-top-1  { padding-top:  1px !important; }
    &-top-2  { padding-top:  2px !important; }
    &-top-3  { padding-top:  3px !important; }
    &-...

    &-bottom-1  { padding-bottom:  1px !important; }
    &-bottom-2  { padding-bottom:  2px !important; }
    &-bottom-3  { padding-bottom:  3px !important; }
    &-...

    &-width-1  { padding-right:  1px !important; padding-left:  1px !important; }
    &-width-2  { padding-right:  2px !important; padding-left:  2px !important; }
    &-width-3  { padding-right:  3px !important; padding-left:  3px !important; }
    &-...

    &-right-1  { padding-right:  1px !important; }
    &-right-2  { padding-right:  2px !important; }
    &-right-3  { padding-right:  3px !important; }
    &-...

    &-left-1  { padding-left:  1px !important; }
    &-left-2  { padding-left:  2px !important; }
    &-left-3  { padding-left:  3px !important; }
    &-...


}
```

### HTML Use:

```
<div class="listItem margin-top-6 padding-width-14">
    ...content here...
</div>
```

---

Any ideas?

Thank you so much for your time and thoughts on this everyone!

Comment: Well, hardcoding this kind of stuff (i.e. various sizes especially in pixels) into HTML classes is barely "smarter" utility classes. In fact it's a pure CSS anti-pattern. (OK, you may have some Bootstrap "col-md-6" etc. as an example but it's more like an exception - there just were *no* other ways to do it at the time it was invented).

Comment: It's not a problem to convert all this into [loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) (so thousands of such classes can be generated with just two or three lines of Less code). But... no, seriously, you're not going to provide a dedicated class for every possible CSS property with every possible value, are you?

Comment: After all if you need to hardcode your sizes into HTML you can use the initial vanilla HTML syntax for that: `<div class="listItem" style="margin-top: 6px; padding-left: 14px">`, no room for CSS in such approach.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: ALL: I would agree with you about the fact it's really not "smarter". I would consider myself a veteran CSS Purist and this would be the antithesis of that purity. I've been tempted by pure programmers and their relentless practice of inline styling. While drinking that koolaid, I thought to create "helper classes" so they can continue their ways in a "smarter" simpler way. For all of the great and constructive responses to this question you all have helped me refocus on the importance of separating form, function and style...to that I thank you. I have abandoned this approach accordingly.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: I didn't think about it, but you are also correct that this would just create an endless loop `</handSlappedToForehead>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry to break it to you but this is working *harder not smarter*.

Why go through the trouble of generating a plethora of CSS classes to make micro adjustments to the box model of an element?  Just use the built-in feature of HTML: the `style` attribute.

Instead of:

```
<div class="listItem margin-top-6 padding-width-14">
    ...content here...
</div>
```

You can do:

```
<div class="listItem" style="margin-top: 6px; padding: 0 14px;">
    ...content here...
</div>
```

...and not have to generate any magical classes.

If you want to work even smarter, you can move these kind of micro-adjustments into a CSS file, attaching them to a meaningful class name:

```
<div class="listItem listItem-special">
    ...content here...
</div>
```

Then, you can use the power of LESS (ie. [parametric mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature)) to shorten the CSS you need to write:

```
.listItem-special {
  .padding-width(4);
  margin-top:6px;
}
```

And here's the mix-in used above:

```
.padding-width(@width){
  padding-left: (@width)px;
  padding-right: (@width)px;
}
```

Having your styles abstracted by the class name `listItem-special` lets you re-use those styles multiple places in your markup.  Furthermore, when you have need to change the styles for `listItem-special` across your site, you only need to update the CSS definition of that class!

It's generally considered a best practice to have your styles separate from your markup.  There are lots of resources on the topic.  [Here's one from Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/20/decoupling-html-from-css/).

Comment: @Jonathan_Wilson: Question "answered"...well addressed really because after reading your Answer and other's comments I realize that this question can't be answered with using LESS nor should be be used in practiced.  Your explanation on leveraging mix-ins is nice and has helped me scope LESS's role when using it. Thank you...

Comment: ...I suppose what I was thinking LESS might be able to do—which it cannot—would be to identify a class name that is built up with keywords and be able to then build the styling on-the-fly sort of like a method...but that really would be a JavaScript thing and also not really provide the separation of form, function, and style that should be practice.  JavaScript could pick apart a class name like 'margin-left-5' and then generate and inline style of `style="margin-left: 5px;"` but then how would that be any better then a hard coded inline style.